# String compare on a bool

Tags: php, conditional-statements, boolean-operations

I'm pretty sure this is a simple fundamental flaw in my newb PHP knowledge, but I was surprised when the following happened:

[image]

`$result` is `TRUE`... so why is it considered equal to the string "email"? I'm guessing this is because, technically, it's a `bool` and it isn't false? So when it's compared against a string (e.g. "email") it returns true.

Should I change my method to return as the result as a `string` containing "true" (instead of `return true;` on success), or is there another way I should be doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please just paste your code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @TJ, The reason I posted a screenshot is because it shows the contents of `$result`, and also that it passed the conditional test. Plus it's literally three lines of code.

Comment: AH! its not my code going against the laws of programming, its just PHP!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, `true` is equal (`==`) to a non-empty string. Not identical (`===`) though.

I suggest you peruse the [type comparison table](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: Not completely correct! Empty string ("") and string zero ("0") are considered FALSE. All the others are TRUE!

Answer (score 3):

It returns true because php will try to convert something to be able to compare them. In this case it probably tries to convert the string on the right side to a bool which will be true in this case. And true == true is ofcourse true.

By doing $result === "email" (triple =) you tell PHP that it shoudn't do conversions and should return false if the types don't match.

Answer (score 1):

`if($result === "email")` will do the trick but personally I would never go this way.

Comment: Why would you never go that way?

Comment: personally I would go with 2 variables. one for a valid result, another for a previously defined error. Improves code readability, but I think it's purely a personal coding style. Should have left this annotation.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Use a string compare function rather than ==