# model return value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I store the return value from my model in a `$result`:

```
$result = $this->absensi_m->absensi();
```

Based on what i return in the `absensi()` function, the value of `$result` will be one of these :

- FALSE
- 'sudah absen' (a String)
- 1 (indicating success)

Then i try to see the `$result` value using `echo $result;` and it returns **1**

But, i get a strange error when i try to use `$result` for some validations :

```
        if($result == FALSE)
            $data['result'] = 'Anda Belum Terdaftar, Silahkan Daftar Dahulu :D';
        else if($result == 'sudah absen')
            $data['result'] = 'Anda Sudah Absen Hari Ini :D';
        else 
            $data['result'] = 'Selamat Datang, '.$this->input->post('txtNama').'! ^^';
```

Although the value of  `$result` is **1**, the second if (`$result == 'sudah absen'`) always return **TRUE**.

Whats going on here?Thanks :D

This is the `absensi()` function in my model :

```
public function absensi() {
        $nama = $this->input->post('txtNama');
        $tanggal = date('Y-m-d', now());

        $this->db->select('umat_id');
        $terdaftar = $this->db->get_where('msumat', array('nama' => $nama));

        $row = $terdaftar->row_array();
        $sudah_absen = $this->db->get_where('msabsensi', array('umat_id' => $row['umat_id'], 'absensi_tanggal' => $tanggal));

        if($terdaftar->num_rows() != 0 && $sudah_absen->num_rows() == 0)
        {
            $data_umat = array(
            'umat_id' => $row['umat_id'],
            'status' => 'H',
            'absensi_tanggal' => date('Y-m-d')
            );

            return $this->db->insert('msabsensi', $data_umat);
        }
        else if($sudah_absen->num_rows() != 0)
            return 'sudah absen';
        else
            return FALSE;
    }
```

**ANSWER :**
I will answer here because you may be confused with a lot of comments/conversation.

I realized whats going on by using `var_dump()` and `echo` (**Thanks to both answers below**):

```
$result = $this->absensi_m->absensi();
var_dump($result);
echo $result;
```

The `var_dump()` returns `bool(true)` while the `echo` returns 1. This means that this problem is occured because i think the `$result` value is 1(integer), while the real value is TRUE(bool).

The conclusion is : echoing a variable with a TRUE(bool) value will result 1(integer), so use the `var_dump()` instead of `echo`.

Comment: @BlazeTama I was right with the answer btw. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938221/string-compare-on-a-bool

Just to be convinced I asked another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462279/php-if-condition-with-boolean and got downvoted, didn't realize question was asked previously. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first you can't return:

```
return $this->db->insert('msabsensi', $data_umat);
```

do this:

```
 $this->db->insert('msabsensi', $data_umat);
 return ...-> 1 or true or what you need
```

then you  should do:

```
if(!$result){
            $data['result'] = 'Anda Belum Terdaftar, Silahkan Daftar Dahulu :D';
        }
    if($result == 'sudah absen'){
            $data['result'] = 'Anda Sudah Absen Hari Ini :D';
         }
       if($result && $result !== 'sudah absen'){
            $data['result'] = 'Selamat Datang, '.$this->input->post('txtNama').'! ^^';
          }
```

then use `var_dump();` to check what result is:

```
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: nope I was in the process of adding the comment. Actually I like your hair style (y). You're doing exactly the same what he's doing adding the braces wouldn't help much. Checking for !$result or FALSE both are same

Comment: Its not me, and i upvoted it :D
Yes, i know something like this will work(playing with if position, i just need to switch the 2nd with 3rd), but what i want is the explanation of whats going on. Thanks :D

Comment: @ro ko check better my answer i corrected enteire  if sintaxt too

Comment: @BlazeTama i need your method ansensi() pls

Comment: @BlazeTama It was me, he was referring to me :) Not sure how that works and your doesn't though.

Comment: @donotusetabtodigitthisnick was the second statement if from the beginning or you edited it, if you didn't edit it my mistake; sorry for it still not very convincing answer. Let's fix it (y) I agree on that.

Comment: @BlazeTama check i updated answer, you can't return a db method, use some value in that *return*, also check new if statements, all will works fine now ;)

Comment: @donotusetabtodigitthisnick Thank you very much for your help :D Yes, your answer is true, but what i really want is the explanation on whats going on in my code :D

Comment: @BlazeTama i told you what's going on, you can't return a db method and you should use a correct if statements

Comment: I accepted your answer because you tell me to use the var_dump(), the answer is : echo will convert true to 1 :D Thanks for your effort :D
And we can return a method (at least in CI)

Comment: @BlazeTama i think all CI methods returns TRUE or FALSE, so take care on this ;) , so, in CI, to check if a method returns true use **if(method()){}** , to check if method is returning false use **if(!method()){}**

Comment: @donotusetabtodigitthisnick okay, thanks for your additional help :D

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this is happening? are you sure `$result=1`?

I find it hard to believe. Here's a [fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e9efb3fdeec4d44b266ed0b179a2eec8c1247ff8) output to your code

your function returns `true` not `1`

you should add `else if($result === 'sudah absen')` to strictly check for the result.

Comment: Do you think its because i get the value (1) NOT from 'return 1;' but from codeigniter (from '$this->idb->insert()')? Yes i'm very sure, i can provide a screenshoot and full code if you want :D

Comment: @ro ko this is not a fix $result === 'sudah absen' it's exactly he same to $result == 'sudah absen' , be serious ;)

Comment: @donotusetabtodigitthisnick seriously?? http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Thanks :D, but why when i use echo $result;, the value that appear is 1, not TRUE?

Comment: @BlazeTama it depends on what your absensi() method is returning

Comment: @BlazeTama yes for echo $result or print will output 1, well that's how php works (or may be I don't know the reason). try var_dump to see the type.

Comment: @donotusetabtodigitthisnick i think the method is returning 1, because when i echo it, the value is 1, not TRUE :D

Comment: === means identical i.e. type should be same as well.

Comment: @BlazeTama the right way to check what somenthing returning is using *var_dump();* not *echo* echo is used only for strings, maybe your method is returning TRUE and echo TRUE ; prints 1

Comment: @ro ko rly for me you can remove === part from your answer, rly not usefull

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, its too bad i can only give 1 upvote and accept 1 answer (which is suited the best for other reader/visitor) :(

Comment: @ro ko i think you can remove your -1 i'll remove mine ;)

Comment: @donotusetabtodigitthisnick I'll leave it be, just going with documentation. Cool with me for remoing -1 part.

Comment: @BlazeTama Oo uhmm you newbie :D and question is newbie, but uhm ok i'll upvote you you honest dude