# PHP if condition with boolean

Tags: php

Why does this [happen](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d5fff6ee86bc7c62d7624a39a1070cff770ad4aa)?

```
<?php $result = true ;
    if($result == 'SOME TEXT')
        echo 'why is this true? why is this printed?';        
    else
        echo 'when this should be printed?'
?>
```

Please explain, I am not looking for alternative method.

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=php+type+juggling of course a duplicate

Comment: Masters!!! just cause I couldn't find old question it means a -1 sure!! . I found it interesting and asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your expression, you are comparing a boolean with a string.  The string gets coerced to `true`.

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

As stated before, use `===` to compare both value and type.

Comment: Well, I find kind it idiotic but it is how it is, so let's flow with it for now.

Comment: Your fine, aim to learn something during every time you visit SO!

Comment: ofcourse I am fine :D. It was just that I find the logic behind it idiotic :P. Any way thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use `==` operator instead of `===`. 
In your case `==` doesnt rely on operands type, instead of `===`

Comment: For mode details - see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: so 'some text' equals to true ?? that is how I am suppose to interpret it ?

Comment: if we disregard the type i.e. btw I do know about === not very convincing answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of PHP's auto type conversion; and since you're not comparing by type as well (===), it's considered TRUE. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is a list of what is considered empty, but it's also considered FALSE:

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> "" (an empty string)
>
> 0 (0 as an integer)
>
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
>
> "0" (0 as a string)
>
> NULL
>
> FALSE
>
> array() (an empty array)
>
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Everything else is basically considered TRUE.

Comment: Sometimes I ask myself why I even bother...

Comment: @Shomz hehe harsh indeed. Guess asked wrong question on wrong day.

Comment: The statement everything else is considered true is correct but I would say it confused people and that's why the vote down. Should say when evaluating, 'whatever string' == true or true == 'whatever string', the outcome will always be true. It's like saying `if ('some string')` which unless the string is empty... or '0'..., will evaluate to true. Just be more clear in your answer.

Comment: @zgr024 ... or unless the string is '0' (should I downvote you for that?). That's why it says **basically** so that anyone with any sense of logic would be able not to take it literaly...

Comment: Edit your answer to include "Everything else is basically true when using ==".. and I'll upvote

Comment: I'm not buying reputation points... so do whatever you want.

Comment: Buying??? I simply stated I would reverse my down vote which I can't do unless you edit.

Comment: Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the php operator documentation..

In your case, you are saying with `==` that a boolean value of "true" is equal to a text value of 'SOME TEXT' but are NOT of the same data type. PHP returns true in this case because if just assumes they are similar if you disregard the data type.

If you used `===` then it would consider the data type and therefore will produce a value of false.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) - spread the word.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing a boolean with a string, the string will be auto-converted to a boolean.

According to the PHP-documentation, any string that is not `null` or `empty` (or zero) will be converted to True.

So your comparison is like  True `==` True.

If you use the `===` operator, you are also checking that both values are of the same type.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting